# dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused AWS CodeBuild EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, aws-codebuild, amazon-eks

I'm encountering following error message when I'm trying to deploy to EKS Cluster even I've already added CodeBuild IAM role to `aws-auth.yaml` like

```
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/codebuild-eks
  username: codebuild-eks
  groups:
    - system:masters
```

> error: unable to recognize "deployment.yml": Get
> http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080:
> connect: connection refused

And here is my codebuild command:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - curl -o kubectl https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.11.10/2019-06-21/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
      - chmod +x ./kubectl
      - mkdir -p $HOME/bin && cp ./kubectl $HOME/bin/kubectl && export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
      - kubectl version --short --client
      - curl -o aws-iam-authenticator https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.13.7/2019-06-11/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator
      - chmod +x ./aws-iam-authenticator
      - mkdir -p $HOME/bin && cp ./aws-iam-authenticator $HOME/bin/aws-iam-authenticator && export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
      - aws-iam-authenticator help
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the pre_build phase...
      - echo Logging in to Amazon EKS...
      - mkdir -p ~/.kube
      - aws s3 cp s3://ppshein-eks/config ~/.kube/config
      - export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config
      - aws eks --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION update-kubeconfig --name $AWS_CLUSTER_NAME
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the build phase...
      - echo Change directory to secondary source
      - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      - echo List directory
      - ls -la
      - kubectl get pods --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
      - kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
```

Problem is when CodeBuild run this `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml` statement, I've got error message but above one `kubectl get pods --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config` is working fine.

Please let me know which area I've missed to add or configure. Thanks.

Comment: I'm no CodeBuild expert, but it looks like those phases are independent of one another; thus, you'll need `- export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config` in your `build: commands:` also, or do the right thing and set that as a variable for your whole pipeline, if CodeBuild is smart enough to allow that

Comment: @mdaniel I've tried already and the result is No.

Answer (score 1):

These errors indicates that kubectl was unable to reach the kubernetes server endpoint at 127.0.0.1:8080, or the local host. Since you have configured kubeconfig with the command `update-kubeconfig`, it seems multiple configs are being merged [1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#merging-kubeconfig-files) due to this command:

```
- export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config
```

To see the resultant config that kubectl sees, run this command before the failing command:

```
- kubectl config view                      # Add this
- kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
```

To fix, I recommend to change as follows in pre_build phase:

```
- export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config
```

Or, use '--context' flag with kubectl to select the correct context.

```
- export KUBECONFIG=file1:file2
- kubectl get pods --context=cluster-1
- kubectl get pods --context=cluster-2
```